# How to make the View Snap to Keyboard

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

My MasterDetail app won't
The keyboard won't snap to the bottom of the view, it overlaps it.
Main View is a contentpage
Wrapped In (MasterDetail Page).

I've placed some elements at the bottom of my main Contentpage via VerticalOptions="end" and they are at the bottom of the page when I scroll(scrollview  with button inside grid (with highest z-index)), but they are covered when the keyboard is opened(from editor sibling to button inside grid). I've tried setting this code:

```
<Activity Android: 
windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

in AndroiManifest.xml but it doesn't work.

[default page view, not my app but same structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VHqB.png)

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fL2f.png)

[Actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E77Fn.png)

Comment: a picture illustrating the problem would probably help

Comment: You could download the source file from the MS docs about Soft Keyboard Input Mode on Android. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode

Comment: @wendy I can't add this, it says the 'WindowSof...' method does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Place the content you need to move inside a ScrollView and it will shift when the keyboard appears

Comment: Hmm, you see I don't want my bottom Toolbar to scroll, I want it to always be visible to the user. Is there a property that will make it remain in place when you scroll?

Comment: @jason added screenshots (didn't know I could only do so on Desktop View of page)

Comment: @Code_Student09 Where do you add the code? Have you try the sample code i provided?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about keyboard covering your controls,

For android:

Add in this your MainActivity after LoadApplication(new App());

```
        App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().
        UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

For ios refer this [link](https://xamgirl.com/adjusting-elements-when-keyboard-shows-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: I can't add this, it says the WindowSof... method does not exist in the current context.